# Eclipse RAP Proxy Servlet Issue

Tags: eclipse-rap

I have a RAP application. When I launch the application from eclipse everything is working find. I can go to the browser an open the application.

However, when I build the product and then start the application from the generated product I get the error 404 when trying to access the application thorugh the browser.

I have checked the logs and I can see the bundles are loaded and everything looks nominal. Also I can not see any other error message.

This is the plugin.xml file:

```
<extension
     id="ssp.oasis.agent.entrypoints"
     point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.entrypoint">
  <entrypoint
        path="/sspagent"
        applicationId="com.lsespace.ssp.oasis.agent"
        id="ssp.oasis.agent.entrypoint"
        brandingId="ssp.branding"
        >
  </entrypoint>
</extension>
```

I type the following on the browser 127.0.0.1:7171/sspagent and then I get the HTTP ERROR 404

Obviusly, I am missing something and it is related to the entry point configuration and jetty but I have no idea what it can be.

Could somebody point my in the right direction or tell me a way to troubleshoot this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to some bundle versions mixed up and or missing. The wierd thing is that there were no error messages. Nevertheless when I realize and corrected the missing/wrong version bundles it worked out.